# NodeJS, Mongo : Sending and storing json as a field for every user

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, server, database

I am using node.js server with mongodb as a database.
Every signed-up User will have one long JSON string (about 500 to 2000 character long ) along with their credentials. That will be send to server through post request.
I'm thinking that storing raw JSON string in database might overwhelm server so, one option I can think of is, uploading JSON as a file on Amazon S3 and storing the link but I'm open for all opinions! 
So my questions are; 
1- what is the best way of storing long JSON file/string for each signed-up user? ( in mongo Users collection )
2-How do you think should I send JSON in request as a string in a field or binary?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First `500-2000` is not that long. Simply save that in your database. Here is a schema to get you started

```
{
  data: {type: Object},
}
```

`Object` is used to store json type data. As far as sending content goes, simply post them inside data field and use data encoding as `json` that way you don't have to do any additional processing while storing the content to mongo database.

Comment: Hey thanks,
I was on the assumption that string was long. But how long character is really long to store it as field on database and/or send it directly as a field on the post? So moving further I know what is long what is not?
Also please consider that every user who logs-in to the server can list about 100-150 user ( with their data included ) so that's another thing for database to handle.

Comment: Look at documentation for mongodb specifically on document limits.